# vue 3 watch individual state property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

My setup function:

```
  setup() {

    const state = reactive({
      // .....
      venueFilter: null,
    })


    const venueFilter = ref(state.venueFilter);
    watch(venueFilter, ()=> {
      console.log('invoked watch');
      if(venueFilter) {
        doSomething();
      }
    });

    return {
      ...toRefs(state),
      //.....
    }
  }
```

The watch above is not getting fired(`console.log('invoked watch');` is not getting printed when `state.venueFilter` changes in the template. So how do I watch the `state.venueFilter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make a ref from a property of a reactive object like that.  This line:

```
const venueFilter = ref(state.venueFilter); //venueFilter will not react to changes in state.venueFilter
```

Instead, you can pass in a getter function as the first argument to watch that returns a value:

```
watch(()=>state.venueFilter, ()=> {
  console.log('invoked watch');
});
```

[Here's a working example to demonstrate](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

You also could have called toRefs(state) first and passed in the venueFilter ref created from that.

Comment: worked like a charm.  FWIW, if you want get current and prior values, just tweak to the following `state.venueFilter, (new_, old_)`.  The first parameter is the current new value, the second hold the previous value.